Finding variations of a word in wordnet
I'm working on a wordgame that needs a corpus of text with part information (including ambiguous words like cut [n/v/a])
I thought I could iterate through wordnet.words() and collect everything I need, but it looks like it's missing a lot of derived or tensed words, and I can't seem to pull the derived words from their roots, just similar words
ex:
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
wn.synsets('behave')
    [Synset('act.v.02'), Synset('behave.v.02'), Synset('behave.v.03')]
wn.synsets('behaving')
    [Synset('act.v.02'), Synset('behave.v.02'), Synset('behave.v.03')]
behavioral_synset = wn.synsets('behaving')[2]
behavioral_synset.lemmas()
    [Lemma('behave.v.03.behave'), Lemma('behave.v.03.comport')]
behavioral_synset.lemmas()[1].derivationally_related_forms()
    [Lemma('bearing.n.03.comportment')]
behavioral_synset.lemmas()[0].derivationally_related_forms()
    []

Ideally I want to iterate over all words, including any variations I can think of for any nouns, verbs, or adjecives, but with what I thought was a simple test case, I can't seem to get from the synset of 'behave' to the present participle of 'behaving'
Additonally, if anyone knows a better dataset I could be using, let me know.
